# Searching a particular text in DOM

Tags: java, dom, jsoup

I have a HTML/JSP's DOM with me, I want to search a particular text inside a DOM and need to build the XPath for the element which contains the text. Using Jsoup API.Building a xpath is working fine

I am able to search the text if it is a value of the element or the value of the attributes of the element. Suppose if a text is there in the DOM without any tags , and if text is contained in span nodes, how do I can search?

Comment: Side Comment: How does this question concerned with `java`?

Comment: @smit He's using http://jsoup.org/. So it must be server side, a java applet, or some sort of offline processing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Solutions

There are a few different solutions.

### jsoup Selector

The [jsoup API](http://jsoup.org/apidocs/) has a [Selector class](http://jsoup.org/apidocs/org/jsoup/select/Selector.html) that implements [pseudo-selectors](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/). Specifically:

- `:contains(text)`
- `:matches(regex)`

These will return a list of elements that contain the search text. You'll have to try it to see if they return the parent container or the exact child, or some combination.

### jsoup Element

The [Element class](http://jsoup.org/apidocs/org/jsoup/nodes/Element.html) has a few methods that may prove useful:

- [Element.getElementsContainingOwnText](http://jsoup.org/apidocs/org/jsoup/nodes/Element.html#getElementsContainingOwnText%28java.lang.String%29)
- [Element.getElementsContainingText](http://jsoup.org/apidocs/org/jsoup/nodes/Element.html#getElementsContainingText%28java.lang.String%29)
- [Element.getElementsMatchingOwnText](http://jsoup.org/apidocs/org/jsoup/nodes/Element.html#getElementsMatchingOwnText%28java.lang.String%29)

These methods allow retrieval of elements or parent elements that contain a given text or regex pattern.

### String Conversion

1. Convert the HTML to a string.
2. Search for text elements as normal (e.g., regular expression).

This has the disadvantage that if the string you want to match is the same as the value for an attribute or the value for a node name, it will return false positives.

## Resources

See the [String API](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html); useful functions might be `indexOf` and `split`.

See the [Pattern API](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html) for constructing regular expressions.

Comment: Thanks Dicarlo, Searching the text through regex will help. But If I does that how I can get the specific node which contains that text. It is needed for building XPath

Comment: Assuming you know where the text is, you could do another search from the text looking for the nearest match on a regular expression that matches html nodes. However, this hardly seems to be the best route, I am not completely familiar with java libraries for parsing html, but there must exist libraries that take care of this functionality for you.

Comment: After reading a bit of jsoup, it seems what you want to do is simply get all of the elements of the DOM using the JSoup API, and search each elements text for the text you are looking for. Then you have the element as well as the text.

Comment: It appears you can also use the pseudo-selectors `:contains(text)` and `:matches(regex)` to find elements that contain `text` or `regex` respectively. See http://jsoup.org/apidocs/org/jsoup/select/Selector.html.

Comment: Thanks Dicarlo you gave me nice directions, Using selectors also we can search the texts, like query the span nodes in the DOM and check the text value of it.